# Unable to get PivotTables property of the Worksheet class

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to write a VBA code to automatically refresh a pivot table:

```
PivotTableName = newname + "PivotTable"
ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(newname).PivotTables(PivotTableName).RefreshTable
```

newname is name of my sheet.
PivotTableName is name of my pivot table.

But I'm running into this error:

```
 Unable to get the PivotTables property of the worksheet class
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using quotes correctly around `newname` and `PivotTableName`?  You haven't provided ANY code other than that one line, so it's not clear whether those are literals or variable names.  Why don't you provide ample code so people can help you?

Comment: Edited!
Also, I'm not using quotes because newname and PivotTableName are variables and not values.

Comment: Okay.... but is `newname` null? You don't show that now. What makes you so certain that `newname + "PivotTable"` is actually the name of a worksheet?  Again with the limited code.

Comment: I can confirm that neither of them are null. I have checked that.

Comment: Is the worksheet protected?

Comment: No. Its not protected.

Comment: In the Immediate Window, what does `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("newname").PivotTables(1).Name` return? Replace the "1" with whichever PivotTable you want. It *has* to be a misspelling of the PT name even though you're sure it's not.

Comment: When I tried : ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(newname).PivotTables(1).Name, it returned Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Try `ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets("ActualSheetNameInQuotes").PivotTables(1).Name`